# How to create topics from command line in Kafka REST proxy

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest

I am using Kafka rest proxy, but not whole Confluent Platform just Kafka rest with my Kafka brokers. But I am not able to create topics from command line by the following command.

```sh
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test.
```

I want to know is there any other way out.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I have installed only schema-registry and Kafka rest  not whole confluent platform, now when I try to execute commands to create topic It doesn't give any response. I want to know how san I craete topics

Comment: You can easily do the same through this command: curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8082/topics/mytopic' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{
  "key_schema": "{\"type\":\"string\"}",
  "value_schema": "{\"type\":\"string\"}",
  "records": [
    {
      "key": "somekey",
      "value": "somevalue"
    }
  ]
}'

Answer (score 1):

The command you have tried out is not meant to interact with the REST Proxy Server of Kafka, but rather interacting with the Kafka cluster directly.

According to the [Confluent REST Proxy API Reference](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#crest-long-api-reference) the creation of a topic is only possible with the REST Proxy API v3 that is currently available as a preview feature.

> "The API v3 can be used for evaluation and non-production testing purposes or to provide feedback to Confluent."

An example of a **topic creation request** is presented below and documented [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#post--v3-clusters-(string-cluster_id)-topics):

```sh
POST /v3/clusters/cluster-1/topics HTTP/1.1
Host: kafkaproxy.example.com
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "topic_name": "topic-1",
      "partitions_count": 2,
      "replication_factor": 3,
      "configs": [
        {
          "name": "cleanup.policy",
          "value": "compact"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Using `curl`:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" \
          --data '{"data":{"attributes": {"topic_name": "topic-1", "partitions_count": 2, "replication_factor": 1, "configs": [{"name": "cleanup.policy","value": "compact"}]}}}' \
          "http://localhost:8082/v3/clusters/<cluster-id>/topics"
```

where the **`cluster-id`** can be identified using

```sh
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" localhost:8082/v3/clusters
```